# Django queryset by username in user model

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I've
models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User) #from contrib.auth,...
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default="")
    descripcion = models.TextField(default="")

    # Valor por defecto, "Pagina de +nombre usuario"
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.titulo:
            self.titulo = "Pagina de " + self.user.get_username()
        super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
 def ShowUserPage(request):
    UsuarioElegido = request.path.split('/')[1]
    UsuarioModel = UserProfile.user.get_user(UsuarioElegido)
    return HttpResponse(UsuarioElegido)
```

I wanna get "titulo" and "descripcion" of UsuarioElegido. UsuarioElegido is the request.path for example /"root". But I can't get it Help?

getting this error: ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor' object has no attribute 'get_user'        UsuarioModel = UserProfile.objects.filter(user.username=UsuarioElegido)

but I don't know how to get it. Tried this before

```
         UsuarioModel = UserProfile.objects.filter(user.username=UsuarioElegido)
```

EDIT: I've just tried this, but Django can't finde my ShowUserPage in views :/?

```
def ShowUserPage(request):
    UsuarioElegido = request.path.split('/')[1]
    UsuarioModel = User.objects.get(username=UsuarioElegido)
    UsuarioModel = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=UsuarioModel)
    return HttpResponse(UsuarioElegido)
```

Comment: Is `UsuarioElegido` the `user` attribute?

Comment: There's quite a long wrong here. Have you done the tutorial? For example, you shouldn't be splitting the path manually; you should use the url pattern to extract the username via regex.

Comment: regex? Oh, I understand, but.. I print it and it works. I should change it as the way you are telling me about.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't have to analyze `request.path` on your own and extract all necessary parts of the URL. You can map this using `urls.py` file. For example like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^user/(?P<username>\w+)$', views.ShowUserPage),
]
```

And your `ShowUserPage` view method that handles this request has following signature:

```
def ShowUserPage(request, username)
```

Second, if you want to look for the user by its name, you can use following query:

```
UserProfile.objects.get( user__username=UsuarioElegido )
```

It will search by `username` attribute of the native Django class for User.

Comment: thanks ! Where can I map this using urls.py? I think that I've done it before, but I don't remember... doc?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `username` is unique:

```
UsuarioModel = UserProfile.objects.get(user__username=UsuarioElegido)
```

Use `__` (double underscore) to [follow relations in lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

Comment: I've never seen __username 
yes is unique is from django auth db